# Shared folder can't be access from different IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, shared-folders, sharing

i have 1 PC and 1 laptop at my office. due to our IT policy, any LAN connected device will given IP 10.1.1.x while connection over WIFI will given 10.1.2.x.

so, PC is 10.1.1.x and laptop is 10.1.2.x. the problem is, laptop can access shared folder on pc but pc can't access shared folder on laptop.

pc can ping with no problem. only can't access shared folder. try many thing (forget ssid and reconnect, reconfigure shared folder permission) but not success.

office use AD to connect to network. both device running windows 10.

kindly advise on how to solve this.
thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using [UNC syntax](http://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/files-sharing/how-do-i-connect-to-a-shared-folder-on-the-network/) allows access to a remote folder even though it does not show in Network in Windows Explorer.

For example, if the folder is `C:\\MyShare` on the laptop, IP 10.1.2.1, create a desktop shortcut to `\\10.1.2.1\MyShare`. Sometimes the initial access to that link may fail, but a subsequent click works, for some reason.

Comment: i already try to access either by hostname (\\laptop\shared) or ip (\\10.1.2.x\shared). unsuccessfull.